# at UNNotification I get different userInfo values than set values in UNNotificationRequest Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, nsnotificationcenter, unnotificationrequest

I have a function that sets the `UNNotificationRequest` with some parameter passed in, I than put those parameters in `userInfo`so I can get them back and use them when opening the local notification. The print of it shows I'm assigning correct values passed in. The problem is that I get some other values when I print `userInfo` in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. I cannot see why this is happening, can you spot what I'm doing wrong here?

This is the `function`that sets the notification and the output prints:

```
func setRouteNotification(_ date: Date, onWeekdaysForNotify weekdays:[Int], snoozeEnabled:Bool,  onSnooze: Bool, soundName: String, routeName: String, index: Int) {

            configureCategory()
            // Notification content
            let routeCheckNotificationContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            let datesForNotification = correctDate(date, onWeekdaysForNotify: weekdays)
//            routeCheckNotificationContent.title = "Hello!! Are you ready to cycle?"
            routeCheckNotificationContent.title = "Ciao!! Pronto ad andare?"
//            routeCheckNotificationContent.body = "Check route for alerts?"
            routeCheckNotificationContent.body = "Controlliamo se ci sono ostacoli lungo il tuo percorso?"
            routeCheckNotificationContent.categoryIdentifier = Id.notificationCategory
            routeCheckNotificationContent.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: soundName + ".mp3")
            print("      set notification is: date: \(date), onWeekdaysForNotify : \(weekdays), snoozeEnabled : \(snoozeEnabled), onSnooze: \(onSnooze), soundName: \(soundName), routeName: \(routeName), index: \(index)")

            let repeating: Bool = !weekdays.isEmpty
//            routeCheckNotificationContent.userInfo = ["snooze" : snoozeEnabled, "index": index, "soundName": soundName, "routeName": routeName, "repeating" : repeating]
            routeCheckNotificationContent.userInfo = ["posticipa" : snoozeEnabled, "indice": index, "Suono": soundName, "Titolo percorso" : String(describing: routeName), "repeating" : repeating]
            print("routeCheckNotificationContent.userInfo at setting notification is: \(routeCheckNotificationContent.userInfo)")
            //repeat weekly if repeat weekdays are selected
            //no repeat with snooze notification
            if !weekdays.isEmpty && !onSnooze{
            }
            syncAlarmModel()
            var counter = 0
            for d in datesForNotification {
                if onSnooze {
                    alarmModel.alarms[index].date = Scheduler.correctSecondComponent(date: alarmModel.alarms[index].date)
                }
                else {
                    alarmModel.alarms[index].date = d
                }
                //trigger
                let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute,.second,], from: d)
                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)

                // Notification Request
                let uuid = UUID().uuidString
                let routeNotificationRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Route Notification Request\(uuid)", content: routeCheckNotificationContent, trigger: trigger)
                // Add request
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(routeNotificationRequest) { (Error) in
                    if Error != nil {
//                        print("something went wrong with adding notification")
                    }
                }
//                print("added request\(uuid)")
                scheduledNotifications.append(counter)
//                print("scheduled notifications are \(scheduledNotifications.count)")
                counter = ( counter + 1 )
            }
//            print(alarmModel.alarms)
//            print("dates for notification are: \(datesForNotification)")
        }
```

output prints:

```
routeCheckNotificationContent.userInfo at setting notification is: [AnyHashable("repeating"): true, AnyHashable("indice"): 0, AnyHashable("Titolo percorso"): "aaa", AnyHashable("Suono"): "Zen", AnyHashable("posticipa"): false]
```

but in `AppDelegate`:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.getDeliveredNotifications { (receivedNotifications) in
            for notification in receivedNotifications {
                let content = notification.request.content
                print(" Body \(content.body)")
                print(" Title \(content.title)")
                let rotta = content.userInfo["Titolo percorso"]
                print("rotta is: \(rotta)")

                print(content.userInfo as NSDictionary)
            }
        }
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        //        audioPlayer?.play()
//        alarmScheduler.checkNotification()
    }
```

output prints:

```
Body Controlliamo se ci sono ostacoli lungo il tuo percorso?
 Title Ciao!! Pronto ad andare?
rotta is: Optional(Scegli un percorso)
{
    Suono = Suono;
    "Titolo percorso" = "Scegli un percorso";
    indice = 0;
    posticipa = 0;
    repeating = 0;
}
```

Body and Title are correct, but the rest is not..where am I missing connection for those wrong values?
Many thanks as usual

Updates:

I made some new prints from every place that I set those values an they are all correct, but in `AppDelegate`i get the values from this line:
`addEditController.segueInfo = SegueInfo(curCellIndex: alarmModel.count, isEditMode: false, label: "Percorso", mediaLabel: "Suono", mediaID: "", routeLabel: "Scegli un percorso", repeatWeekdays: [], enabled: false, snoozeEnabled: false)` 
SegueInfo is just a struct that holds values until they are replaced with actual chosen values, and I do update them..

```
struct SegueInfo {
    var curCellIndex: Int
    var isEditMode: Bool
    var label: String
    var mediaLabel: String
    var mediaID: String
    var routeLabel: String
//    var routeId: String
    var repeatWeekdays: [Int]
    var enabled: Bool
    var snoozeEnabled: Bool
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found where the problem was. I wasn't getting the values in the response. So I removed code from `applicationDidBecomeActive`and got the values from `didReceive response` in the appropriate Action and it's now working as expected.
I hope this will help others.
The entire function is:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        switch response.actionIdentifier
        {
        case Id.checkActionIdentifier:
            print("Check tapped")

            let content = response.notification.request.content
            let rotta = content.userInfo["Titolo percorso"] as! String
            RoutesArray.routeName = rotta
            print("rotta is: \(rotta)")
            print(" Body \(content.body)")
            print(" Title \(content.title)")

            NewMapViewController.checkCounter = 1

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController : UINavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            let vc = initialViewController.viewControllers[0]
            vc.performSegue(withIdentifier: "alertToMapSegue", sender: nil)

        case Id.waitActionIdentifier:
            print("Wait tapped")

        default:
            print("Other Action")
        }

        completionHandler()
    }
```